# Azure function deployed using azure devops still using old code

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

I setup Continuous Build and Release  using azure devops using Deployment Center but  the function is still calling old code unless re Publish it directly from VisualStudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issues in the past. What fixed it for me was using Package Deployment. In your DevOps build pipeline, use Azure App Service Deploy version 4, go to "Additional Deployment Options" and use "Run From Package" as the deployment method.